# update Bitwig Studio-8 with deb

Tags: updates, deb

For a Ubuntu Studio **beginner** , how do you **UPDATE** an already existing *Bitwig Studio-8 track* DAW after having recently downloaded the update files (Bitwig Studio 3.2.8 deb) from the *Bitwig Studio* DAW ?

Comment: Try `sudo apt install Downloads/filename.deb`

Comment: YES, including "sudo apt auto remove" , simple tho  thank-you so much !